# One URL scheme for both Ios and Android

Tags: android, ios, react-native, deep-linking

So I am in the mids of inplementing url-schemes in my app (React-native and for both Android and Ios) but I am having some trouble with the html implementation of the url schemes. 
I figured out that for android you have to use:

`<a href="intent://Something/#Intent;scheme=SomeApp;package=com.SomeApp;end">`

But for IOS only this link works: `<a href="SomeApp://Something">`

Is there a way to allow both the android and IOS app to use the same link to open the app? I figured that it's quite common to ask that but I couldn't find any resource on the internet that was usefull for this. I could try to make some JS code to try both the links but that's not really a pretty solution (Android doesn't respond to the IOS link so I can run that one first and then the Android link after that)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: why dont you try with Platform.OS === 'ios' ? and then . link>

Comment: It isn't on the react native side, that works fine it is on the html implementation side but thanks for the suggestion!, the "ios" link doesn't even register in the android app so I can't use it

Comment: So you're looking to add Deep Linking to your app. You need to register your custom scheme. It can be the same for both iOS and Android. This article is pretty helpful I think: https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e